# C# aspNetCore webApi Через какие HTTP методы лучше отправлять команды?

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core

Есть классическое REST WebApi, для CRUD операций над коллекцией объектов

1. GET - получить все
2. GET(int id) - получить по id
3. POST (model m) - добавить новый
4. PUT(int id, model m) - редактировать объект по id значением m
5. DELETE(int id)- удалить объект по id
6. ??? - команда

Мне нужно еще интерфейс для команд.
например команда Build - на основе этого объекта создать Другой объект
ну или например просто на фронте будет кнопка "отправить по сети".

**Через какие HTTP методы лучше отправлять команды?**

```
[GET/POST] -????
public Task<IActionResult> Build(int id)
{

}
```

Comment: для себя я выработал правило: если *команда* создает то тогда это `post` иначе `put`, `get` это только получение данных для форм

Comment: Да, на базе выбранного объекта, создает другой объект к которому есть доступ через свой WEB api. Т.е. просто для себя определить правила использования POST/PUT

Comment: Спасибо! Вас понял.